# Add a transparent coloured background to png with transparency

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to do something very simple but somehow can't manage to do it.

I have an PNG with transparent areas.

How to add a background layer filled with some RGBA color such as `rgba(255,0,0,128)`?

I'm using imagemagick version 6 in its command line form.

This would be the PNG image for example:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in ImageMagick by flattening the image against a color.

```
convert sayduck.png -background "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)" -flatten result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Hum actually, not really. If you see, now the background isn't `rgba(255,0,0,128)` but `rgba(255,0,0,255)`. We lost the transparency of it.

Comment: Same mistake as emcconville - used your values without thinking about how alpha is specified in ImageMagick. Need to change alpha in rgba from 128 to 0.5. Corrected now.

Comment: thanks ... I had it all along, did not realise the alpha chanel

Answer (score 1):

First thing I can think of is to draw the color and composite under the image.

```
convert input.png \( +clone -fill 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)' -draw 'color 0,0 reset' \) +swap -composite output.png
```

[image: output.png]

Although I'm sure there's quicker ways.

Comment: Same than the answer bellow: If you see, now the background isn't `rgba(255,0,0,128)` but `rgba(255,0,0,255)`. We lost the transparency of it.